# Generic type assignment says incompatible type for more restrictive assignment

Tags: java, generics

I have a variable of following type

```
Pair<String, Class<?>> test;
```

I am trying to create it like this:

```
Class<? extends Animal> animal = Tiger.class;
test = Pair.create("tiger", animal);
```

The code gives me "Incompatible types"(while creating Pair with animal). Although variable test definition permits class of any type and animal defines boundary of any child class of animal, which is more strict than the original one. So shouldn't this assignment work?

Comment: I've hit the same problem with generics in Java, they're implemented using type erasure which is wonky at best. If your test also used ? Extends Animal, it would work.

Comment: @JeffWatkins Thanks, But this doesn't make any sense right, When (Class<?>) means that it can hold any class type, it should not have a problem keeping more restrictive types.

Comment: pls post the Pair.create method code, or at least the signature with return type

Comment: This works for me: http://pastebin.com/GFf8buMf

Comment: @guido This a standard class in android library android.util.Pair here is a link to it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html

Comment: Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock  I am even more confused now, I wrote the same code in my IDE(IntelliJ-Idea) running on JDK7 and it shows error.

Comment: @guido http://i.picresize.com/EPeM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tiger` is subtype of `Animal`, but `Class<Tiger>` is *not* a subtype of `Class<Animal>`. The parent of both `Class<Tiger>` and `Class<Animal>` is `Class<?>`.

Similarly, `Pair<String, Class<? extends Animal>>` is not a subtype of `Pair<String, Class<?>>`, they are infact distinct objects, even if `Class<? extends Animal>>` is a subtype of `Class<?>`.

To make it easier to understand, think of it in terms of collections: if you got a `Pair<String, List<?>>`, and you assign a `Pair<String, List<? extends Number>>` to it; you could then be able to add a `String` to the list. http://ideone.com/dcXnWs

In Java8, you code works http://ideone.com/AkK7Zv; honestly, I am not sure what the compiler does additionally (still have to delve in new features). Anyway, as you can see the compiler error for following samples is quite explanatory:

- Java8: http://ideone.com/ZRGbyr

  `error: incompatible types: List<Class<? extends Animal>> cannot be converted to List<Class<?>>`
- Java7: http://ideone.com/dcXnWs (same code)

  `error: incompatible types`

Comment: Java 8 improves type inferences (mostly when functions return generic types). Possibly this is the cause for the code working with java 8. See http://blog.decaresystems.ie/2014/04/09/better-type-inference-in-java-8-generics/ for more information.

Comment: More specifically, Java 8 knows about the type of the return assignment and infers `<String, Class<?>>` for the method invocation.

Answer (score 3):

Possible explanation why it works in Java 8 (which has improved type inference):

```
public static class Pair<A, B> {
        public static <A, B> Pair<A, B> create(A a, B b) {
                return new Pair<A, B>();
        }
}

public static class Animal {}
public static class Tiger extends Animal {}

public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        Class<? extends Animal> animal = Tiger.class;
        Pair<String, Class<?>> test = Pair.create("tiger", animal);
}
```

According to the [Java Generics Subtyping Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html):

1. It is true that: `Class<? extends Animal> extends Class<?>`
2. It is false that: `Pair<String, Class<? extends Animal>> extends Pair<String, Class<?>>`

Because of 2. it does not work in Java 7, but Java 8 utilizes 1.:

```
Pair<String, Class<?>> test = Pair.create("tiger", animal);
```

Java 8 inferes that argument a has type `String` and argument b has type `Class<?>`. Because 1. is true, it can cast the second argument to `Class<?>`, which then fits to the type of the variable `test`.

So because it can cast the single argument before passing it to the method, it does not have to cast the returned result (which isn't possible).